# Riak /priv/ directory not created

Tags: riak, riak-cs

I have installed Riak using apt on Ubuntu 14.04 and I can't find /riak/priv. On git wiki page I have found a todo #TODO - explain where Riak's priv/ is located.

Can someone help with this please ?

This is the exception after copy the files for riak explorer.

```
 [error] <0.474.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.474.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:'not'({file,"/usr/lib/riak/lib/riak_core-2.1.5-0-gb02ab53/ebin/riak_core.beam"}) in re_config:is_standalone/0 line 227 in application_master:init/4 line 133
```

Comment: If you are trying to install Riak Explorer, start with the standalone version. I had no problems installing it, whereas the instructions for the patch version are confusing. I was able to figure out that /path/to/riak/lib/ actually translates into /usr/lib/riak/lib/,  and that /path/to/riak/priv probably translates into /usr/lib/riak/lib/riak_core-<build>/priv/, but that still won't work.

Comment: Yes, agree I had made the same suppositions and tried them as you said but no luck same exception.

Comment: As I said, the tool is experimental. That said, I was able to install its standalone version a while ago. You may want to open a bug or try riak-users mailing list http://lists.basho.com/mailman/listinfo/riak-users_lists.basho.com

Comment: It's been a year since someone asked this question. I'm still stuck on it. Anyone make any progress since last year?